# Executing delayed chained payment, partially to one of the many secondary receivers

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

We have a situation, where sender will do digital goods(services) from multiple provider, but sender do the payment in one transaction in delayed chained payment mode, so initially primary receiver will receive all money.

Now the primary receiver will have to execute payment to send money to the secondary receivers. However in our case, we have to pay only one receiver at a time. But Execute API, will pay to all the receivers at once.

Is there any other way, so that we can execute part of the payment of that transaction to particular receiver.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a delayed chained payment there is no way to pay secondary receiver(s) individually at different intervals.

You could do what you're saying, though, by ditching the delayed chained payment method altogether and using another method.  For example, if you just use a regular checkout method (Payments Standard, Express Checkout, etc.) and let the money go to a primary account, then you could use build separate Pay requests from the primary to a secondary receiver at any time you want to.  You could do the same thing using MassPay, too.